# Symfony2 - Methods for all controllers

Tags: php, symfony

Developing my Symfony2 application, i would like to, kind of like in Ruby on Rails, to have methods available in all controllers. In RoR controllers simply inherit after `ApplicationController` and that is where you put all the methods. But what is the Symfony way, what is good practice here?

Functionality I want is very simple actually, something similar to this:

```
public function showAction()
{
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
}
```

I can load current user here, and I would like this function to be terminated before every action, without, of course, copying the code into every single controller.

Comment: Be aware that the standard Symfony 2 base controller class already has a getUser() method.  It's worth taking a look at the source code to see what it can do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use services for this.

**Acme/DemoBundle/MyService/MyService.php**

```
<?php
namespace Acme/DemoBundle/MyService

class MyService {

   public function myFunction(){
        [...]
   }

}
```

**Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    my_service:
        class: Acme/DemoBundle/MyService/MyService
```

Or .xml version

**Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/config/services.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services
        http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"
>
    <services>
        <service id="my_service" class="Acme\DemoBundle\MyService\MyService">

        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Then in a controller

**Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/MyController.php**

```
$this->container->get("my_service")->myFunction();
```

To make it available in all your bundles just update each bundle's services config file accordingly.

Documentation is [available here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#what-is-a-service)

Comment: should i make special folder for MyService class inside of Acme\DemoBundle directory?

Comment: You can pretty much do as you please but yes that is good practice.

Comment: To clarify, for this specific example yes. But you can do as you like as long as you update the namespace accordingly.